# Webpack Angular2 JQuery Plugin Issue

Tags: angular

I'm using Angular2 Typescript for my application. During the initial loading of the application it is taking more time as it is downloading individual js files resulting upto 12 MB. I was suggested to use WebPack in order to bundle all the js files in to single file. I've configured necessary setups, but during application loading I get the following exception with regards to Jquery usuage. I've coded using jquery selector ($) from typescript to perform some UI selection, use jquery methods but during load time it is throwing the below exception. I've even included necessary dependency in Webpack.config.js for jquery, so it compiles without any issues but during onload exception is being thrown.

> EXCEPTION: TypeError: $ is not a function app.bundle.js:53511
>   EXCEPTION: TypeError: $ is not a functionBrowserDomAdapter.logError @
>   app.bundle.js:53511BrowserDomAdapter.logGroup @
>   app.bundle.js:53521ExceptionHandler.call @
>   app.bundle.js:16196(anonymous function) @
>   app.bundle.js:19188ZoneDelegate.invoke @ zone.js:323onInvoke @
>   app.bundle.js:24163ZoneDelegate.invoke @ zone.js:322Zone.run @
>   zone.js:216(anonymous function) @ zone.js:571ZoneDelegate.invokeTask @
>   zone.js:356onInvokeTask @ app.bundle.js:24154ZoneDelegate.invokeTask @
>   zone.js:355Zone.runTask @ zone.js:256drainMicroTaskQueue @
>   zone.js:474ZoneTask.invoke @ zone.js:426 zone.js:461 Unhandled Promise
>   rejection: $ is not a function ; Zone: ; Task: Promise.then ; Value:
>   TypeError: $ is not a function(…)consoleError @ zone.js:461_loop_1 @
>   zone.js:490drainMicroTaskQueue @ zone.js:494ZoneTask.invoke @
>   zone.js:426 zone.js:463 Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: $ is
>   not a function(…)consoleError @ zone.js:463_loop_1 @
>   zone.js:490drainMicroTaskQueue @ zone.js:494ZoneTask.invoke @
>   zone.js:426 app.bundle.js:74155 this.showHome >> true

Plugin:

```
plugins: [
new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
jQuery: 'jquery',
$: 'jquery',
jquery: 'jquery'
})
```

Angular version: 2.0.0-rc.5

Browser: all

Language: TypeScript 1.8.10 | ES5]

Node (for AoT issues): node --version = 6.3.1

Package.Json File

```
{
"name": "angular2-quickstart",
"version": "1.0.0",
"scripts": {
"build:tsc1": "tsc --rootDir app --outDir dist",
"postinstall": "typings install",
"build": "webpack --progress",
"build:prod": "webpack -p --progress",
"serve": "webpack-dev-server --progress"
},
"license": "ISC",
"dependencies": {
"@angular/common": "2.0.0-rc.5",
"@angular/compiler": "2.0.0-rc.5",
"@angular/core": "2.0.0-rc.5",
"@angular/forms": "^0.3.0",
"@angular/http": "2.0.0-rc.5",
"@angular/platform-browser": "2.0.0-rc.5",
"@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "2.0.0-rc.5",
"@angular/router": "3.0.0-rc.1",
"core-js": "2.4.0",
"jquery": "^3.1.1",
"reflect-metadata": "0.1.3",
"rxjs": "5.0.0-beta.6",
"zone.js": "0.6.12"
},
"devDependencies": {
"ts-loader": "^0.8.2",
"typescript": "^1.8.10",
"typings": "^1.0.4",
"webpack": "^1.13.1"
}
```

Webpack.config.js :

```
var webpack = require("webpack");

    module.exports = {
    entry: {
    app: './app/main.ts'

    },
    output: {
    path: './dist',
    filename: 'app.bundle.js'
    },
    module: {
    loaders: [
    {test: /.ts$/, loader: 'ts'}

    ]
    },
    resolve: {
        extensions: ['', '.js', '.ts', '.css'],

    },
    plugins: [
    new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
    jQuery: 'jquery',
    $: 'jquery',
    jquery: 'jquery'
    })
    ]
    };
```

Comment: Do not use Jquery in an Angular 2 project.

Comment: Thanks Nguyen, is there any other way, like any plugins available in Angular 2 for using jQuery functionality.

Comment: No. Jquery and Angular2 are 2 different things.

Comment: Did you ever resolve this issue?